# Using different character(s) as linebreak

Tags: macvim

Given an input file of the form

```
#1. This STUFF
Content related to 1
...and some tips 

#4. Fouth heading 
4para
4para


#3. 
3para
3para
```

I'd like to be able to sort it to get:

```
#1. This STUFF
Content related to 1
...and some tips 

#3. 
3para
3para

#4. Fouth heading 
4para
4para
```

specifically I'd like to be able to do this with a command that looks like:

```
 :sort break="#"
```

i.e. change the linebreak character to "#" for the duration of the sort.

Is this possible in any way? A similar question might be "Can I sort the fuctions in a python file alphabetically by name?"

Comment: I think it would be easier to do with a tool like [awk](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk) rather than Vim. Awk might not be the easiest tool to master it for this kind of manipulations it is very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

```
for id in reverse(range(1,100)) | sil exe printf('g/\v^#%d\./,/\v.*(\n#\d+\.|%%$)/ m0', id) | endfor
```

Loop from 100 to 1, execute [:h :global](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Aglobal) for each number, use [:h :m](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Am) to move each block to file start.
This method is slow, see update for a better way.

Break down of `g/\v^#3\./,/\v.*(\n#\d+\.|%$)/ m0`:

- `/\v^#3+\./` find line starts with `#3.`.
- `,/\v.*(\n#\d+\.|%$)/` this a [:h [range]](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%5Brange%5D) , it starts from current line, ends at line followed by line starts with `#\d+\.` or end of file.
- `m0` move to file start.

**update**

A more efficient method:

```
%d | put ='#'.join(sort(split(@@, '\v#\ze\d+\.'),'N'),'#') | 1d
```

- `%d` delete whole file into default register
- `put =` [:h :put](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Aput) text from register [:h quote=](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#quote%3D) after current line (line 1).
- `'#'.join(sort(split(@@, '\v#\ze\d+\.'),'N'),'#')` split by `#`, sort numberical, join by `#`, add leading `#` for 1st item.
- `1d` remove 1st line.

Comment: I learned quite a lot reading this answer.

Comment: Hopefully "get in the habit of using global in a loop" is not one of your learnings. ;) In practice, even though we're looking at `O(n^2)` efficiency, it might perform just fine for reasonable value of `n`. If not, I'd go with statox's advice and use `awk` or equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a special marker for end-of-line, join all lines in a section into one line, sort the lines, and replace the markers by linefeeds:

```
" Add an empty line at the end of file so the search pattern
" in the :global command will work.
:$put =''
" Mark every end-of-line.
:%s/$/<EOL>/
" Join all lines in a section starting with a hash up until
" the line before the next section or the end of the file.
:g/^#/;/\(^#\|\%$\)/-1join!
" Get rid of the additional empty line.
:$d
" Sort the file by the numbers after the hash signs.
:sort n /^#/
" Re-insert the linefeeds.
:%s/<EOL>/\r/g
```